# Python groupby imputing

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have a dataframe with 200 rows and 151 columns, with the output variable being of the type `object`.

I am trying to impute `Null` values in the input variables (150 columns) with the mean value of the column section grouped by output variable.

Is there a way to use sklearn Imputer in this instance? Does anyone know an example I could follow? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code of what you have tried?

Comment: I tried the following............    for column in df:
       df[column] = df.groupby("column_name").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))....................I think it did the job, but (a) it took ages to compute (over 5 minutes); (b) did not use the machine learning algorithm.    Wondering if there was a better way of doing it.   Thanks

Comment: Can you add it to the body of your question? :)